# Raspberry Pi 2 or Odroid U3 enough performance to run ROS and AR-Tag Pose Estimation?

Tags: pose, ar-pose, newtags, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello experts,

the title says it all. I want to implement a Pose Estimation of AR-Tags on a Raspberry Pi 2 / Odroid U3 or similar board. But I have no clue, if these boards have enough performance to deliver a "smooth" estimation...
A visual output is not required or can be attained through a ssh access from my pc (to save performance).

Would be nice if someone could share his experiences with a Raspberry Pi 2 / Odroid U3 (or similar board) and ROS...

Thanks for your help!

Greetings Johannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205221/raspberry-pi-2-or-odroid-u3-enough-performance-to-run-ros-and-ar-tag-pose-estimation?/) by [MVR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21891/mvr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not got Ondroid U3 or RPi2, however I have run [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) AR-tag node with [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) node on [Beagle Bone Black board.](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK)

I got the satisfactory results. Messages with marker's pose was published each 100 ms (10 Hz) for 320x240 resolution.
For resolition 640x480 I have got only 2-3 Hz. CPU loading was about 60% for 320x240 and about 90% for 640x480.
I think that Ondroid U3 and RPi2 are more powerful, so you can use them for marker detection.

Best Regards,
Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MVR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21891/mvr/) on 2015-03-19**:
good news :) if it works on a single core, the RPI2 or Odroid U3 quad cores should have enough power (even for 640x480 (or higher)). Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2015-03-19**:
It is truth, if the AR-tag detector supports several cores.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have only gotten simple programs to work on the rpi2 all of the computation is done on my workstation.

---

Originally posted by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) with karma: 143 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MVR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21891/mvr/) on 2015-03-18**:
Thanks for your answer. So computer vision (with ar-tags) isn't possible with a rpi2? Do you also use other boards like cubieborads oder odroids?